# Can python's input() return a boolean value based on the argument its given?

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is some control logic that I am trying to set up, and it would be useful if I could have input() return a boolean value based on input from the user.  Does input() already compare a value to another in how it inherently works?

I can imagine myself having to write a function based on what input() already does if it does not have a boolean return feature.

So far, my code consists of a while loop. It had an exit condition that I need to use more specifically. I have left it out from below

```
str = "original"
while True:
    print(str)
    time.sleep(1)
    str = "changed"
    if str == "changed":
        changed = True
```

Actual Results:

```
original
changed
changed
changed
changed
```

At some point, this loop should just print out what a user gives to input() with a time delay between each print statement, but what I have done here does not use input and only exits with a keyboard interrupt.

I don't know which needs to be addressed first to complete this code: making the exit from the while loop independent of the keyboard interrupt or the processing of the user input.

Comment: `input()` always returns a string, it returns whatever the user typed. If you need additional logic, you do that after calling `input()`.

Comment: @AndressaCabistani when using function input() on REPL, raw_input of the argument passed in by the user is returned. This is what led me to think that input() could return a boolean value and simultaneously be used to close the while loop based on the boolean return it gives.

Comment: Python 2.x has two input functions, `input()` and `raw_input()`, where `input()` would evaluate the input as an expression. Python 3 got rid of this distinction, and `input()` just returns the string like the older `raw_input()` function did.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking about in this question. `input` always returns a string, which answers the question in the title (no, it never returns a bool), but I have no idea what you actually want. It's hard to answer a question about a loop using `input` when your example loop doesn't use `input` at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `input()` always returns a string.

But you would just compare that string with another

```
s = "original"
changed = False
while not changed:
    print(s)
    time.sleep(1)
    s = input("> ")
    if s == "changed":
        changed = True

print('s = {}'.format(s))
```

Note: `str` is a built-in python class. Don't name a variable as the same

Comment: Instead of a `changed` variable, just use `break` to end the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
 import time

    s = "original"
    changed = False
    while not changed:
       time.sleep(1)
       sprev = s
       s = input("> ")
       if s != sprev:
           changed = True
```